# MySQL Query to search for all columns where 2 columns share the same 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

I'm not entirely sure how to word this, and I'm new to SQL in general, but basically in my `group_memberships` table I have columns `user_id`, `group_id`, and `permission_level`. I want to see if two users (user1 and user2) share the same group (i.e. they're both part of the same group) *and* if user1 has `permission_level` of `1` and user2 has a `permission_level` of `0` (i.e. user1 is user2's admin).

That query might be pretty intense, but I'm not sure. I'm having a tough time even googling how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a self join:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM group_memberships gm1 -- for the "first" user
JOIN group_memberships gm2 ON TRUE -- for the "second" user
 AND gm1.group_id = gm2.group_id
 AND gm1.user_id != gm2.user_id -- prevent joining to the same tuples
WHERE TRUE
AND gm1.permission_level = 0
AND gm2.permission_level = 1
-- additional conditions can go here, eg:
-- AND gm1.userid = X
-- AND gm2.userid = Y
```

Comment: Oooh, think im like 95% there. I think there's a typo in your query above too. I think `AND gm1.user_id != gm2.user_id` is what you wanted? Only thing now i'm fiddling with is how to set specific `user_id`s to look for. I don't want _all_ matches of this just user1 and user2. Thank you!

Comment: yes of course. thanks for pointing that out. fixed it. also added extra conditions